# jquery: toggle data from input to text and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to Jquery and javaScript, and I am trying to do the following:

I have a text field in a table. I want to be able to change it to a input field, and when the user clicks a button, save it in the db (by using a Ajax call) and change it back to text again.

I've been able to do exactly that, but the strange thing is that it only works once, after saving, you can not edit the same field again, unless I refresh the page.

The HTML is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>My data field :</td>
    <td id="MyDataField">123 <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editMyDataField" style='float: right' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript is:

```
$('#editMyDataField').on('click', function() {
  //First clikck, change the table cell into a input field, with the current text value and change icon
  $('td#MyDataField').html($('<input />', {
    'value': $('td#MyDataField').text()
  }));
  $('td#MyDataField').append('<i class="fa fa-check" id="editMyDataField" style="float: right"/>')

  //Second click, do something with the vale (for instance Ajax call), change field back to text with the new value, and change icon
  $('#editMyDataField').on('click', function() {
    alert("Save value in db: " + $('td#MyDataField input').val())
    $('td#MyDataField').html($('td#MyDataField input').val() + '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editMyDataField" style="float: right"> ');
  })
})
```

I've created a JSfiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2zkbvhoL/

I have a hunch that by repacing the icon, I'm somehow "losing" the connection to the click function, but am not sure how I should solve it.

Comment: Regarding losing the button, I recommend hiding it using CSS (I'm still reading...)

Comment: @ErikL did any answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the structure would be a better solution.

Instead of: `123 <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editMyDataField" style='float: right' />`

Why not: `<span class="text">123</span><input class="edit" type="text"><button type="button"><i ...></i></button>`?

```js
$(function(){
  $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
    var $field = $(this).closest(".field");
    if (!$field.data("editing")) {
      $field.data("editing", true);
      $field.find(".edit-input").val($field.find(".text").text()).show();
      $field.find(".edit-btn").hide();
      $field.find(".ok-btn").show();
      $field.find(".text").hide();
    }
  })
  
  $(".ok-btn").click(function(){
    var $field = $(this).closest(".field");
    if ($field.data("editing")) {
      $field.find(".edit-input").attr("disabled", true);
      runAjax($field, function(){
        $field.find(".edit-input").attr("disabled", false);
        $field.data("editing", false);
        $field.find(".edit-input").hide();
        $field.find(".edit-btn").show();
        $field.find(".ok-btn").hide();
        $field.find(".text").show();
      });
    }
  })
  
  function runAjax($field, cb) {
    //your ajax here. Below is just a delay for demoing
    setTimeout(function(){
      //If ajax OK, you would want to change the text to the input's value
      $field.find(".text").text($field.find(".edit-input").val());
      if (typeof cb === "function")
        cb();
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-editing="false" class="field">
  <span class="text">123</span>
  <input class="edit-input" type="text" style="display:none">
  <button type="button" class="edit-btn">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="ok-btn" style="display:none">OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm, but when I try to recreate it using i (icon) tags, I run into trouble. As soon as I enable the line to remove the edit icon when editing, I also lose the ok icon. You can see the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/1b4f1xsu/2/ . Any idea why it works with normal buttons, but not with these icon buttons?

Comment: @ErikL Please note that `<i>` is not a self closing tag. I'm going to sleep so I can't verify it. Could you add some closing tags and check? :)

Comment: @ErikL Also, using the `<i>` tag would not be semantic, I strongly encourage you to use the `<button>` tags for buttons. You can use CSS to change the background and the other styles of the button elements.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. By changing the I tags to buttons and adding a little bit of css I've been able to get it the way I wanted. See: https://jsfiddle.net/1b4f1xsu/3/

Comment: @ErikL Good luck on your project ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
See demo here 
https://jsfiddle.net/2zkbvhoL/7/

<s>Try using</s>

```
$('table').on('click','#editMyDataField', function() {
// your code here...
}))
```

Instead of table you can also use document as well and change it at both the places.

So this code should work for you:

```
$('table').on('click','#editMyDataField', function() {
  //First clikck, change the table cell into a input field, with the current text value and change icon
  $('td#MyDataField').html($('<input />', {
    'value': $('td#MyDataField').text()
  }));
  $('td#MyDataField').append('<i class="fa fa-check" id="saveMyDataField" style="float: right"/>')

  //Second click, do something with the vale (for instance Ajax call), change field back to text with the new value, and change icon
  $('table').on('click','#saveMyDataField', function() {
    alert("Save value in db: " + $('td#MyDataField input').val())
    $('td#MyDataField').html($('td#MyDataField input').val() + '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editMyDataField" style="float: right"> ');
  })
});
```

Changed `editMyDataField` to be `saveMyDataField` on the inside of the function.

Although this is just a quick fix to your solution. You can remove the nested event binding and attach the events separately to the both the buttons(the edit and save icons)

Comment: Use it on the inside as well

Comment: @RinoRaj, See update I am not sure how jsfiddle work so not pasting link from there :) but now I think the code should work